# clear both in css makes a huge height for first child

Tags: html, css

I used a lot of float and clear but in this case I faced with a strange problem.
this is my html code:

```css
    .tablerow{
        border:1px solid blue;
        padding:0px;}
    
    .tablerow .tablerowcolumn{
        height:30px;
        width:15%;
        margin:0px;
        float:right;
        border:1px solid #565656;   
        background-color:#fff; 
    }
```

```html
    <div class="tablerow">
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tablerow">
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

but the result is different from what expected:

[image]

Comment: Its working fine: https://jsfiddle.net/3uz8Lve1/

Comment: Hey brow, `float` not is useful, I suggest you lern `flexbox`

Comment: Can you show the container for the rows and the associated CSS, please?

Answer (score 0):

You code ***works***, but not exactly as expected, since `.tablerow`s haven't `height` property, and they are trying to be as little as possible.

So if you add a height (eg. 100px), you'll get the result:

```css
    .tablerow{
        border:1px solid blue;
        padding:0px;
        height:100px;
    }
    
    .tablerow .tablerowcolumn{
        height:30px;
        width:15%;
        margin:0px;
        float:right;
        border:1px solid #565656;   
        background-color:#fff; 
    }
```

```html
    <div class="tablerow">
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tablerow">
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div class="tablerowcolumn">
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```